# How can I set U-boot CONFIG_MYBOARD_XXXX values from the command line?

Tags: configuration, u-boot

I'm working on custom hardware, and have added a new `myboard` board to my U-boot repro. The `make` pattern is very standard:

```
make myboard_defconfig
make
```

which sets the U-Boot configuration to the myboard defaults, and then builds the resulting U-boot image. It all works, but I need to take it one step further.

The hardware actually comes in two closely-related flavors, and I need to build slightly different U-Boot images for the two flavors. Rather than defining two completely different boards, I'd like to build the same board type twice, but with a `CONFIG_MYBOARD_XXXX` symbol having different values. My `myboard.c` file will then have an `#if CONFIG_MYBOARD_XXXX == YYYY` test to differentiate the results.

Problem: I want to set `CONFIG_MYBOARD_XXXX`'s value from within my parent `Makefile`, not by running anything interactive like `make menuconfig`.

What's the "right" way to do this?

Comment: IMO the *"right way"* is to completely change your thinking, and have just one common version of U-Boot for your two boards. Have code that can *identify* which board is in use.  The fewer variations of programs that Engineering, Production, and Support have to deal with is better.  One extreme example of this practice is Nvidia's Unified Driver: for a version of Windows OS, there is just one driver for all Nvidia graphics adapters.

Comment: Point well taken, but my "two different flavors" are actually the same board in different boot configurations. So, the `make` process will build both types to create a flexible boot image. (And, thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

The U-boot `make` process has a lot of magic in it, and there seems to be a number of unstated rules on how files need to be named. So, I assumed that the `configs/myboard_defconfig` file, and the argument to `make myboard_defconfig`, had to match the official name of my board followed by `_defconfig`.

Turns out I was wrong: these files can be named anything, as long as they end in `_defconfig`. So, to have two closely-related versions of myboard, I just have two different defconfig files, e.g. `myboard_one_defconfig` and `myboard_two_defconfig`, with the configuration values in the two files specifying the configuration for the two different flavors of myboard.

Easy peasy!

Comment: IMO you've started down the path to maintenance/distribution hell.

Comment: This would be true if we were planning on updating our U-Boot version from time to time. However, once this works, we probably won't touch it again for the life of the product. So, getting it working trumps long-term maintenance.